# Is there any way i can optimize this c# code?

Tags: c#, button, optimization

This code segment repeatsmany times in my program, but with other buttons like button 3 and 4, button 5 and 6 etc. i am wondering if it can be optimized or shortened?

```
    if (File.Exists(name1))
                {
                    button1.IsEnabled = false;
                    button1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    button2.IsEnabled = true;
                    button2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.IsEnabled = true;
                    button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    button2.IsEnabled = false;
                    button2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                button1.IsEnabled = true;
                button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                button2.IsEnabled = false;
                button2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```

Comment: Does that works? Something is missing there right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please recheck your question, as the code you posted is incomplete. It's missing an `if` statement to match the last `else`

Comment: @spender bruh i know its not finished.... I just need help on optimizing this exact part

Comment: 1. Give good names to controls. 2. Complex logic with many actions can be split into 2 clear steps: evaluating and acting. 3. It's WPF, look into MVVM, using it will make your code much more clean. 4. No need to disable hidden elements (I guess you are doing it because somewhere else you are using `button1.IsEnabled`, look into MVVM). 5. You question is missing important details, see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the *length* of the code that matters. It is *repeated logic* that should be avoided:

```
private void HideAndDisable(Button b)
{
    b.IsEnabled = false;
    b.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void ShowAndEnable(Button b)
{
    b.IsEnabled = true;
    b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        HideAndDisable(button1);
        ShowAndEnable(button2);
    }
    else
    {
        HideAndDisable(button2);
        ShowAndEnable(button1);
    }
}
```

It leads to a code that:

- is simpler to understand
- can easily be reused
- avoids hidden bugs
- easier to change

Comment: Changing the signature to `params Button[] b` and adding a `foreach` will allow you to call it  on multiples buttons in one go. Like `HideAndDisable(button1,button2,button3)`